# Binding with boost works while with std doesnt, whats the diffrence?

Tags: boost, boost-bind, stdbind

I tried to bind a function with std::bind, it kept saying that there is no overload for my set of arguments. It worked with boost::bind. Whats the diffrence between std and boost bind?

Im using:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2
>
> boost 1.53.0

func declaration and bindings:

```
void Messenger::receiveCallback(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred, char* message, int bufferSize, tcp::socket* socketPtr, void(*onMessageReceivedCallback)(char* message, string hostname, int port, int length));

std::bind(&Messenger::receiveCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, message, bufferSize, socketPtr, onMessageReceivedCallback);//error

boost::bind(&Messenger::receiveCallback, this, _1, _2, message, bufferSize, socketPtr, onMessageReceivedCallback);
```

errors:

> 105 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::bind"
>   matches the argument list
>               argument types are: (void (Messenger::*)(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t bytes_transferred, char
>   *message, int bufferSize, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *socketPtr, void (*onMessageReceivedCallback)(char *message, std::string hostname,
>   int port, int length)), Messenger *, std::_Ph<1>, std::_Ph<2>, char *,
>   int, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *, void (*)(char *message,
>   std::string hostname, int port, int
>   length))  c:\Users\gospo_000\Source\Repos\Messenger\Messenger\Messenger\Messenger.cpp 176 4   Messenger
>
> lots of errors like this one:
>
> Error 81  error C2780:
>   'enable_if::value,std::_BindRx(_thiscall
>   _Farg0::* )(_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t),_Rx,_Farg0,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t>,_Vx0_t,_Vx1_t>>::type std::bind(*Rx (*_thiscall _Farg0::* const
>   )(_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t),_Vx0_t &&,_Vx1_t &&)' : expects 3
>   arguments - 8
>   provided  c:\users\gospo_000\source\repos\messenger\messenger\messenger\messenger.cpp 176 1   tester2

Messenger.h

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include "Connection.h"
#include "Message.h"
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;


class Messenger
    {
   //.............................
          void receiveCallback(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred, char* message, int bufferSize, tcp::socket* socketPtr, void(*onMessageReceivedCallback)(char* message, string hostname, int port, int length));
    };
```

Messenger.cpp

```
void Messenger::receiveCallback(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred, char* message, int bufferSize, tcp::socket* socketPtr, void(*onMessageReceivedCallback)(char* message, string hostname, int port, int length))
{
    if(error)
    {
        string connectionId = getConnectionId(socketPtr->remote_endpoint());
        connections_.erase(connectionId);
        cout<<error.message();
    }
    else
    {
        onMessageReceivedCallback(message, socketPtr->remote_endpoint().address().to_string(), socketPtr->remote_endpoint().port(), bytes_transferred);
        socketPtr->async_receive(
            boost::asio::buffer(message, bufferSize),
            boost::bind(&Messenger::receiveCallback, this, _1, _2, message, bufferSize, socketPtr, onMessageReceivedCallback));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post enough code for us to replicate the error? Or at least paste the exact error. You also have an extra `)` in the `std::bind` line.

Comment: thx, bracket removed, that's not the problem, just a result of copying

Comment: "105 IntelliSense:" - do you mean errors of IntelliSense? Have to tried to compile the code?

Comment: Error 81 error C2780 is a compilation error, isnt it? I tried to compile it but there are lots of compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `std::bind` takes only [5 arguments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) by default. Set _VARIADIC_MAX macro to 10 in order to increase the maximum arg number in variadic templates.

Comment: It seemed to be this kind of problem. This solution works, thank you.